# How to find how many pointers are pointing to a particular node in a linked list?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

Assuming a multiply-linked list (or, say, a circular list with an extra pointer pointing to the HEAD) how can I find which pointers are pointing to a node?

I've read in several places that it's difficult to find the amount of pointers pointing to a node. This implies there's a way, correct?

Comment: scan the entire list and count them. unless you've got a mutually-linked list. e.g. if A->B, then B->A exists already.

Comment: why do you wanna know that?

Comment: It the pointers are only accessible inside the list, you can instrument it with counters. If they are accessible outside, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: You may use a smart pointer with refcounter like shared_ptr instead of raw pointer and return them ouside.
with shared_ptr you can get number of references.

Comment: When writing a data structure, the first thing to do is to be sure about the ownership of the data. ***The elements belong to the user (Are managed by), or to the data structure?*** Thats why you don't have to worry about how many people is using that data. Say, for example, in the standard library the data commonly belongs to the container. Thats why, for example, pointers and iterator to the data are invalidated after container rearranging (Note I'm providing and abstract pov here). And thats why after container destructor the destructors of the elements are called.

Comment: I remember a C exercise where my teachers wrote a circular buffer, but they weren't be coherent about ownership. Since they were using `void*` to store data, they where not sure if that data referenced by `void*`s belong to the buffer or to the user who posted the data. The result was many memory leaks along the exercise. Bad C teachers...

Comment: @juanchopanza Unless a refcounter is used, as Alexander suggested?

Comment: @sgarza62 I was assuming you meant pointers. If you use user defined types instead you can do whatever you want (smart pointers aren't really pointers.)

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, yes you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because pointers in C and C++ are just memory addresses, an object has no way of knowing what points to it. In order to determine the number of pointers to an object, you have to either:

1. Keep track of the number of pointers as you create or delete them
2. Search all possible places that these pointers could be located, and count them.

If instead of using native pointers, you use [`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/), the number of references is counted internally for you. If you use `shared_ptr` to do your circular referencing, you can make one of the pointers in the circle a [`weak_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/weak_ptr/), which works like `shared_ptr` but isn't counted toward the total number of pointers - therefore, circular references get cleaned up properly.